# Is $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{x^2+2y^2}\sin(e^{xy})$ integrable on set K

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Is $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{x^2+2y^2}\sin(e^{xy})$ integrable on set $K=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2<=1, x>0, y>0\}$ I am not sure if my argument is viable. Lets take $y=x$ and check if this function is integrable on this line. 
$$\frac{2}{3}\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\biggl|\frac{\sin(e^{x^2})}{x}\biggr|\geq\frac{2}{3}\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{\sin(e^{x^2})}{x}$$ and this integral does not converge (checked it on wolframalpha, but I think the argument behind could be $\sin(e^{x^2})\approx1+x^2$ is this argumentation enough? Considering I only took the measure zero set of K. If not what is the proper way to solve this?

Comment: So  $\;\sin(\mathrm e^{x^2})>1$?

Comment: right, then it is enough to make it on interval $[0,1/2]$ for instance to make $sin(e^{x^2})$ positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand in absolute value is bounded above on $K$ by

$$\tag 1\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}.$$

Integrating $(1)$ over $K$ using polar coordinates, we get

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^1 \frac{r\cos t + r\sin t}{r^2}\,rdr dt = 2.$$

Thus the original integral converges.

Answer (score 1):

I think by integrable on set $K$ it really means you take the integral on the whole set and see if it converges. But you can easily modify your proof to include a set of non zero measure.

I.e. put $y=ax$ for some arbitrary $a$ and use the same reasoning.

And also yes, it's easy to see the function behaving sort of like $\frac{1}{x}$ at $0$.

Comment: I am not sure on how to cover the set K by lines, as limits would be different..., but is it not enough to check on this one line? As integral of positive function (modulo makes it positive) is greater than zero on the set and it is infinity already on this one line.

Comment: Yeah sure it's just that if you integral a dirac function, that is infinite on a set of measure zero and the integral does not diverge. So basically what you've got to do is show divergence over a non measure zero set. 

You can do polar coordinates and for fixed $\theta$ this is basically just saying $y=ax$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now it is clear to me.

Comment: by integrable, shouldn't we check the continuity of $f(x,y)$ on $int K$ ie $K = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 < 0, x<0, y<0 \}$? the value of integral being finite should be just a special case.

Comment: I think that happens automatically

Comment: indeed, one condition is stronger than the other. Had we just luck here to have an easily observed case of convergence? Otherwise, reasoning is the other way around.

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: The resoning here won't work because there is this r from determinant when making polar coordinates.